# I compile this c file with no errors or warnings but when i run it doesn't return any results

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pthreads

I wrote this code to create two .txt files(prod_in.txt, cons_out.txt). I give to this program three arguments, first the circular buffer length, second how many random numbers and third the seed value for rand_r method.This program is using  two POSIX threads. The first thread is run routine Consumer who make the first txt file(cons_out.txt) and filled up with random numbers and put this number into the circular buffer and when the buffer is full called the second threat. The second run the second routine Producer who read the numbers from the circular buffer and write in the second .txt file(prod_in.txt).

I compile this c file with no errors or warnigs but when i run it the only thing is create the two .txt and nothing else. But after that it is stuck in command and the .txt is both of them empty.

Here is my code. Thanks!!!

```
 #include <pthread.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "circular_buffer.h"
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 pthread_mutex_t lock; 
 circular_buffer *cb;
 struct producer_data{
int thread_id;
int seed;
int num;
}; 
//global variables
int file,file1;
pthread_cond_t cond=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
void cb_init(circular_buffer *cb, size_t capacity, size_t sz)
{
cb->buffer = malloc(capacity * sz);
if(cb->buffer == NULL){
    printf("Could not allocate memory..Exiting! \n");
    exit(1);
    }
    // handle error
cb->buffer_end = (char *)cb->buffer + capacity * sz;
cb->capacity = capacity;
cb->count = 0;
cb->sz = sz;
cb->head = cb->buffer;
cb->tail = cb->buffer;
}

//destroy circular buffer
void cb_free(circular_buffer *cb)
{
free(cb->buffer);
// clear out other fields too, just to be safe
}

//add item to circular buffer
void cb_push_back(circular_buffer *cb, const void *item)
{
if(cb->count == cb->capacity)
    {
        printf("Access violation. Buffer is full\n");
        exit(1);
    }
memcpy(cb->head, item, cb->sz);
cb->head = (char*)cb->head + cb->sz;
if(cb->head == cb->buffer_end)
    cb->head = cb->buffer;
cb->count++;
}

//remove first item from circular item
void cb_pop_front(circular_buffer *cb, void *item)
{
if(cb->count == 0)
    {
        printf("Access violation. Buffer is empy\n");
        exit(1);
}
memcpy(item, cb->tail, cb->sz);
cb->tail = (char*)cb->tail + cb->sz;
if(cb->tail == cb->buffer_end)
    cb->tail = cb->buffer;
cb->count--;
}

struct producer_data producer;
void *Producer(void *pro){

struct producer_data *my_data;
my_data=(struct producer_data *)pro;    
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);  
while(cb->count<my_data->num)
pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&lock);
unsigned int see= (my_data->seed)*(my_data->thread_id);
for(int j=0;j<my_data->num;j++){    
int nu=rand_r(&see);
nu=nu%256;
cb_push_back(cb,(void*)&nu);
if(dup2(file,1)<0)exit(0);

printf("Producer %d: %d\n",my_data->thread_id,nu);
}
close(file);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);


}
void *Consumer(void *id){
char *tmp_read=(char*)malloc(1);
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
int tid=(int) id;
while(cb->count>0){
    cb_pop_front(cb,(void*)tmp_read);
    if(dup2(file1,1)<0)exit(0);
    printf("Consumer %d: %d\n",tid,*tmp_read);
    free(tmp_read);
}
close(file1);
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
if (argc != 4){
    printf("Error: please give correct agrument.\n");
    return -1;
}
int s_size=atoi(argv[1]);
if(s_size<10){
    printf("error: the size of buffer must be greater of 10.\n");
    return -1;
}
int num=atoi(argv[2]);
if(num<1){
    printf("error: the 3rd agrument must be greater of 1.\n");
    return -1;
}
int seedp=atoi(argv[3]);
if(seedp<0){
    printf("error: the 4rd agrument must be greater of 0.\n");
    return -1;
}
int file =creat("prod_in.txt",0644);
int file1 =creat("cons_out.txt",0644);
if((file<0)||(file1<0))exit(0);

cb = (circular_buffer*)malloc(sizeof (struct circular_buffer));
cb_init(cb,num,1);
pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL); 
pthread_t threads,threads1;
producer.thread_id=1;
producer.seed=seedp;
producer.num=num;
int rc,rc1;
int i=1;
rc=pthread_create(&threads,NULL,Producer,(void *) &producer);
 if (rc) {
printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
exit(-1);
}
rc1=pthread_create(&threads1,NULL,Consumer,(void *)&i);
if (rc1){
    printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
exit(-1);
}
pthread_join(threads,NULL);
pthread_join(threads1,NULL);
pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);

}
```

The circular_buffer.h:

```
 #include "stdio.h" 
 #include "sys/types.h"
 #include "stdlib.h"
 #include "string.h"

 typedef struct circular_buffer
 {
   void *buffer;     // data buffer
   void *buffer_end; // end of data buffer
   size_t capacity;  // maximum number of items in the buffer
   size_t count;     // number of items in the buffer
   size_t sz;        // size of each item in the buffer
   void *head;       // pointer to head
   void *tail;       // pointer to tail
   } circular_buffer;
```

Comment: Break it up into smaller tasks and make sure each task does what you expect.

Comment: Aside: pointer arithmetic works well without your intervention. `cb->buffer_end = (char *)cb->buffer + capacity * sz;` should be `cb->buffer_end = cb->buffer + capacity` assuming `buffer` and `buffer_end` are the correct type, which we can't see.

Comment: Please include source for `circular_buffer.h`

Comment: Sorry i forget the circular_buffer.h . I edit my first post and i put the header.

Comment: What do you mean by "debug with no errors"? Debugging is an interactive process, done precisely because there are errors. Do you mean "compiles with no errors"? (or "builds")

Comment: I don't see that the Producer ever gets out of this loop: `while(cb->count<my_data->num) {`